# How to retrieve a substring based on a first list match

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

In a string I need to recover a 7 char substring based on the first match from any item in a list.  If a match is not made it should return an empty string.

I have the following code:

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>()
{
    "TNCO",
    "TNCB",
    "TNIT"
};
string sample = "TNSD102, WHRK301, TNIT301, YTRE234";

//doesn't give an index
bool anyfound = myList.Any(w => sample.Contains(w));

//code that needs replacing
string code = sample.Substring(sample.IndexOf("TNC"), 7);
if (code == "")
{
    code = sample.Substring(sample.IndexOf("TNIT"), 7);
}
```

The list is never likely to be more than 35-40 items and the strings < 50 chars.

Anyone able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: I don't understand. Are the strings in your list the beginnings of the comma-separated items contained in `sample`? You're just trying to find the substring? Like....performing this alrogithm on myList[2] would give you "TNIT301"?

Comment: Could you show what the input to your function is, and given a specific input/s, what is the expected output.

Comment: `int keyIndex = myList.FindIndex(w => samples.Contains(w));` this returns index of 2 is this what you are wanting..? I added code and tested it to give you something that will give the proper results. Check and test the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string val1 = (sample.Split(',').FirstOrDefault(w => myList.Any(m => w.Contains(m))) ?? string.Empty).Trim();
```

Comment: Is the `ToList` call really necessary?

Comment: `ToList()` is not needed since the `string[]` returned from `Split` is already an `IEnumerable<string>`. Nice answer anyway.

Comment: Yep, it is not, my bad, I was using a ForEach before and forgot to remove it. Answer edited

Comment: Also, `FirstOrDefault` returns `null` in the "default" case, not empty string.

Comment: val1 = val1 != null ? val1 : string.Empty;

Comment: @Tomás Use `FirstOrDefault(...) ?? ""` and then trim the result to get rid of the leading blank.

Comment: @Tomás Technically speaking, that's not a cast; it's effectively a coalesce. And this could be shortened by using the coalesce operator ( ?? ) demonstrated in some of the other answers.

Comment: fantastic, thanks again all, will upvote when I get more points :)

Answer (score 1):

This gives you an IEnumerable of all matches:

```
var matches = from code in sample.Split(',')
              from w in myList
              where code.Trim().StartsWith(w)
              select code;
```

To get the first value use FirstOrDefault. Then use the coalesce operator `??` to return an empty string if there was no match.

```
string firstMatch = (matches.FirstOrDefault() ?? "").Trim();
```

Comment: This is most readable to me though i think you would need a code.FirstOrDefault() since he was asking for the first match.

Answer (score 0):

With data sets this small, you can simply split the string and search for the first match:

```
// split the sample string into separate entries
var entries = sample.Split(new char[] {',', ' '},
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

// find the first entry starting with any allowed prefix
var firstMatch = entries.FirstOrDefault (
    e => myList.Any (l => e.StartsWith(l)));

// FirstOrDefault returns null if there are no matches
if (firstMatch == null)
    Console.WriteLine("No match!");
else
    Console.WriteLine(firstMatch);
```

Example output ([**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/QcnBYU)):

```
TNIT301
```

Answer (score 0):

Running this code here returns an Index of 2 based on what you are trying to find.

```
int keyIndex = myList.FindIndex(w => samples.Contains(w));
```

`TNIT301` this is the indexed string value

you could also do the following to return the string value in index position of `keyIndex` variable value.

```
var subStrValue = samples.Split(',')[keyIndex];
```

Comment: Your first line gives the index in myList. The second line however uses this index in the sample string. This gives a wrong result. Try with `string sample = "TNSD102, TNIT301, WHRK301, YTRE234"` and it would return `WHRK301`.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> myList = new List<string> { "TNCO", "TNCB", "TNIT" };
string sample = "TNSD102, WHRK301, TNIT301, YTRE234";
string[] sampleItems = sample.Split(new[] { ',', ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var results = myList
    .Select(prefix => sampleItems
        .FirstOrDefault(item => item.StartsWith(prefix)) ?? "");
```